# Simple PHP Error

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I have a simple php error coming up of which i cannot find the solution to. I inserted in the following code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once '../includes/db.php';  

$address1 = $_REQUEST["address1"];
$address2 = $_REQUEST["address2"];
$city = $_REQUEST["city"];
$postcode = $_REQUEST["postcode"];

mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2', city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."')")

or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

This code gives me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Line 1 is the following in which i think it has nothing to do with the sql statement:

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>
```

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: The error means line 1 in the SQL statement, not the PHP code.

Comment: You have an extra ) in the final string: "')" should be "'"

Comment: You need to delete the extra ")" in your query

Comment: The error is blatantly an **SQL error**, so "line 1" refers to the first line of your SQL query. (Since there's only one line, the error simply refers to your entire SQL query.) Print the query out and check it separately.

Comment: MySQL doesn't know about the surrounding PHP code and as such it's referring to line 1 of the SQL statement (It is only one line). @Merianos Nikos has the fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097498/simple-php-error/8097530#8097530

Comment: @AndrewStubbs: You don't need to link to the answer(s) to this question.  We can all scroll down and see 'em ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change that line:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2', city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."')")
```

to that

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2', city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

You have an extra right parenthesis in the query.

Comment: This should do it, there was an end paren that wasn't needed.

Comment: Mark as answered if that helped you :)

Comment: waiting for the 15min wait to be over :)

Answer (score 3):

1. That is open to [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)
2. Make sure that:

   ```
   UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2', city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."')
   ```

   is a real query.
   Which you can now see that it isn't because of the extra `)` at the end

Answer (score 3):

You have a `)` in the end of the query that's not supposed to be there.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2', city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2', city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

You have a stray `)` at the end of your SQL query.

It should be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2', city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$_SESSION['username']."')")
```

to

```
$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten to place a semicolon at the end?

the right one below:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE customers SET address1='$address1', address2='$address2',city='$city', postcode='$postcode' WHERE username ='". $_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Comment: He has forgot a right parenthesis after the $_SESSION['username'] . "')". The question mark is after the die(). this is one sentence.

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake I didn't really tested it out.

Comment: @Rocket, Yes and no ! :) xaxaxaxa In Greece we use the semicolon as question mark ! ;) Btw, my english are not so good ! :) xaxa

Comment: @MerianosNikos: Interesting.  Didn't know that.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon#Greek_and_Church_Slavonic